# How to Draw on Image Angular2 Ionic2

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, angular, ionic2

I know how to draw in Angular1 Ionic1.

**In my html**:

```
<img ng-src="{{image}}" style="width: 100%">
<canvas id="tempCanvas"></canvas>
```

**In my controller**

```
var startimg="img/face.jpg";
$scope.image=startimg;

var canvas = document.getElementById('tempCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var source =  new Image();
source.src = startimg;

canvas.width = source.width;
canvas.height = source.height;

console.log(canvas);

context.drawImage(source,0,0);

context.font = "100px impact";

textWidth = context.measureText($scope.frase).width;
if (textWidth > canvas.offsetWidth) {
    context.font = "40px impact";
}

context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillStyle = 'white';             
context.fillText('HELLO WORLD',canvas.width/2,canvas.height*0.8);

var imgURI = canvas.toDataURL();

$timeout( function(){
    $scope.image = imgURI;
}, 200);
```

This code would definitely draw HELLO WORLD text on the top of face image.

However, in Ionic2/Angular2, it seems doesn't work. I can't even get the `document.getElementById('tempCanvas')` to work.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Angular 2 Systemjs start</h1>
    <img [src]="image">
   <canvas #layout></canvas>
  `
})    
export class App {
  @ViewChild('layout') canvasRef;
  image = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png';
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let canvas = this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let source = new Image(); 
    source.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    source.onload = () => {
        canvas.height = source.height;
        canvas.width = source.width;
        context.drawImage(source, 0, 0);

        context.font = "100px impact";
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.fillText('HELLO WORLD', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height * 0.8);

        this.image = canvas.toDataURL();  
    };
    source.src = this.image;
  }
}
```

See also the plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/qAGyQVqbo3IGSFzC0DcQ?p=preview

Or you can use custom directive like this:

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[draw-text]' 
})
class ImageDrawTextDirective {
  loaded = false;
  @Input() text: String;
  @HostListener('load', ['$event.target'])
  onLoad(img) {
    if(this.loaded) {
      return;
    }
    this.loaded = true;
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;

    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    context.font = "100px impact";
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillText(this.text, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height * 0.8);

    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  }
}
```

See plunkr for this case https://plnkr.co/edit/BrbAoBlLcbDcx8iDXACv?p=preview

Comment: Hi! I am referring to this piece of code in my application that you provided, it works as expected but I am facing an issue as I am describing here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806865/ionic2-image-overlay-save-and-share). I take photo with camera and then put text on it with this canvas directive but after that how can I share this overlayed image on social media or even save it in my gallery? Also, adding this directive in <img> makes part of the image display on my display(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809608/ionic2-camera-image-do-not-show-entire-image-in-template)

Comment: In `ImageDrawTextDirective` you have a infinite loop. When you do `img.src = canvas.toDataURL();` a load event is trigger and everything in `onLoad` is run again.

Comment: @yurzui i am using the first method you described, but the onload method is not called and the text is not drawn on image, it is an ionic app, ionic 3.9.2 and angular 5.2.10, can you please help me in the right direction?