# ionic2 camera image do not show entire image in template

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to use camera in my ionic2 app. I take picture with following function:

```
takePicture(){
    Camera.getPicture({
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        quality: 100,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000,
        correctOrientation: true
    }).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is a base64 encoded string
        this.base64Image = imageData;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

and display it with following HTML:

```
<img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image" text="{{flavour}}" draw-text crossOrigin style="max-width: : 100%; max-height: 100%;" />
```

However it do not show the complete image I took from the camera in html.
Following is the screenshot:
[image]
and the original image:
[image]

Why there is this difference? How can I show the complete image I took?

Note: I tried changing targetWidth values but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

It was because the directive I am using to add text as an overlay to the captured image.

I removed `text="{{flavour}}" draw-text` and I could see the entire image.